# How to prove $a_1^Ta_1+a_2^Ta_2\le b_1^Tb_1+b_2^Tb_2.$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inequality, vector-spaces

Let $p,q > 0$, $a_1, b_1\in \mathbb{R}^m, a_2,b_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be vectors. Given that
$$\frac{2}{p}\|a_1\|_2^2+\frac{2}{q}\|a_2\|_2^2-\frac{2}{p}a_1^Tb_1-\frac{2}{q}a_2^Tb_2\\+\|b_1-a_1\|_2\frac{2}{\sqrt{pq}}\|a_2\|_2+\|a_1\|_2\frac{2}{\sqrt{pq}}\|b_2-a_2\|_2\le 0.$$

How to show that $a_1^Ta_1+a_2^Ta_2\le b_1^Tb_1+b_2^Tb_2.$

I first try to assume that $p=q$, and then I can cancle $\frac{2}{q},\frac{2}{p}$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt{pq}}$.

$$\|a_1\|_2^2+\|a_2\|_2^2-a_1^Tb_1-a_2^Tb_2\\+\|b_1-a_1\|_2\|a_2\|_2+\|a_1\|_2\|b_2-a_2\|_2\le 0.$$ I think there is no counter example for the above equation.

Then suppose $a_1^Ta_1+a_2^Ta_2\le b_1^Tb_1+b_2^Tb_2$ holds.  The following should hold,
$$-a_1^Tb_1-a_2^Tb_2+\|b_1-a_1\|_2\|a_2\|_2+\|a_1\|_2\|b_2-a_2\|_2\le  b_1^Tb_1+b_2^Tb_2.$$

Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}^{++}$?

Comment: @user7530, $\mathbb{R}^{++}$ means larger than $0$. You have a lot of reputation. You must can guess :)

Comment: @user7530, I correct my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prove that because the assertion is not true. Consider the scalar case $m=n=1$ with
$$
p=1,\,\ q=64,\,\ a_1=1,\,\ a_2=4,\,\ b_1=b_2=2.
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
&\frac{2\|a_1\|^2}{p}+\frac{2\|a_2\|^2}{q}-\frac{2a_1^Tb_1}{p}-\frac{2a_2^Tb_2}{q}+\frac{2\|a_2\|\|b_1-a_1\|}{\sqrt{pq}}+\frac{2\|a_1\|\|b_2-a_2\|}{\sqrt{pq}}\\
=&\frac{2}{1}+\frac{32}{64}-\frac{4}{1}-\frac{16}{64}+\frac{8}{8}+\frac{4}{8}\\
=&2+\frac{1}{2}-4-\frac{1}{4}+1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{-1}4<0,
\end{align*}
but $a_1^Ta_1+a_2^Ta_2 = 17 > 8 = b_1^Tb_1+b_2^Tb_2$.

Comment: ,Hi, thank you. Good counter example. I am checking what I missed.